# SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I have a big problem with SQLite in Java. When I run this query with MariaDB everything works perfectly, but with SQLite not. Does anyone know an answer?

Query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY kills DESC) AS ranking FROM sp_rageffa) AS `*2`
WHERE uuid = 'b71e5129-7216-4d79-b79f-2e3893a6befa';
```

Error:

> SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)

Comment: Welcome to SO.   ```SELECT *, RANK()```  looks strange.

Comment: But it works (at least with MariaDB)

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: You understand that different databases do not use the exact same version of SQL?

Comment: maybe sqlite dont support  RANK() OVER .remove  RANK() OVER and try again?

Comment: SQLite supports [`rank()`](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#builtins).

Comment: Some DBMSs don't allow `*` to be mixed with other result columns, so you have to qualify it, i.e. `SELECT sp_rageffa.*, RANK() ...`. Don't know if SQLite is like that.

Comment: You're using an old version that doesn't have window functions.

Comment: Which version of sqlite are you using?

Comment: SQLite supports RANK(), I'm using the version 3.34.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in the database browser, and there's nothing wrong with your command. Support for that syntax was introduced in version 3.25 of sqlite, and jdbc (the java interface with sqlite) using pretty much the same versioning scheme, so you should make sure you're using a version of jdbc numbered 3.25 or higher.

Comment: I have also tried this via the console of Intellij IDEA, there it also worked without problems. Only when I compile this does not work. I'm using SQLite 3.34.0